# Phonegap Android splash screen not showing

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, splash-screen

I'm building a iOS and Android app (with ionic framework and Adobe Phonegap Build), but can't seem to get the splash screens showing up in Android here's my config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.4" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />

<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="icons/splashscreen/port-ldpi.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="icons/splashscreen/port-mdpi.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="icons/splashscreen/port-hdpi.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="icons/splashscreen/port-xhdpi.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xxhdpi" src="icons/splashscreen/port-xxhdpi.png" />
```

The splash screen images are sizes like this:

```
port-ldpi.png = 240x320
port-mdpi.png = 320x480
port-hdpi.png = 480x800
port-xhdpi.png = 720x1280
port-xxhdpi.png = 1280x1920
```

The path to the images are correct. On iOS it working without any problems.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem? :S

Comment: i found you missing this line : <preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="6000" />

Comment: That didn't seem to work :(

Comment: I have the same problem, if you'll find solution, please share.

Comment: I was able to solve it. I ended up going away from Phonegap Build and using Ionic / Cordova CLI instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at my example demos.
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Splashscreen-Test
It works for both Android and iOS. Implemenation notes are included.
NOTE: AndroidManifest.xml is NOT needed.

Also the splash image MUST be the correct size or at least the correct size ratio so it can stretch it.
Example:320x240 will work for 640x480, etc. Otherwise, you need to use a [9-patch image](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html). I have not tested 9-patch.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the default splash tag which is

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

It's in the documentation: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens

Comment: Is that a requirement?

Comment: Tried to add the default splash in the root, but doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Yes this is a requirement. This is the most common error for splash screens in PG. Check your path, filenames, types and resolutions.

Comment: The default splash screen cannot be a requirement. Since someone declares the splashscreen files for certain screen sizes, they should be recognized and used by the app. By setting the default splashscreen, you just "help" your app use this particular image even if you don't specify images for all screen sizes. This means that even if your different splashscreen sizes are not recognized or have a wrong path, you wouldn't know.